# $NaN being returned in the footer of my table when trying to SUM

Tags: javascript, php

I'm working in PHP. I'm bringing in data from SQL Server 2008 and creating a table. I have a footer that I need to sum each respective column. I would like to make the data in the table drillable. When the data is not drillable, to footer sums everything up perfectly, but when I add the href the footer returns $NaN for that specific column. Here is my code with the footer working correctly (no hrefs):

```
$out = array();

while($data = odbc_fetch_array($resultsSalesOrdersHeader_SalesOrderHeader)) 
{
?>

 <?php 

 $row = array(
    $data['SalesOrder'],  
    $data['Customer'],
    $data['CustomerName'],
    $data['Branch'],
    $data['Salesperson'],
    $data['FinalDate']);

    array_push($row, "$".number_format(($data['PreDateValue']),2));      
    array_push($row, "$".number_format(($data['Adds']),2));
    array_push($row, "$".number_format(($data['Changes']),2));
    array_push($row, "$".number_format(($data['Deletes']),2));
    array_push($row, "$".number_format(($data['Delta']),2));
    array_push($row, "$".number_format(($data['EndingValue']),2));

    $out[] = $row;
}

echo json_encode(array("aaData" => $out));
?>`
```

and a snippet from the footer code is:

```
var iTotalPrice5 = 0;
                    for ( var i=0 ; i<aiDisplay.length  ; i++ ) {
                        var y = aaData[ aiDisplay[i] ][11];
                        var z = y.replace("$","");
                        iTotalPrice5 +=  parseFloat(skipComma(z));
                    }

                    var nCells = nRow.getElementsByTagName('th');
                    nCells[11].innerHTML =    "$"+addCommas(iTotalPrice5.toFixed(2));
```

This brings in the sum perfectly. Here is a snippet of the code I'm using to try and add the hyperlink, but it breaks the footer:

```
array_push($row, "<a href='index.php?p=SOEndingValue&enddate=".$enddate."&startdate=".$startdate."&SalesOrder=".$data['SalesOrder']."' target='_blank'>".
                "$".number_format(($data['EndingValue']),2)."</a>");
```

What do I need to do to include the hyperlinks, and make the footer sum correctly?

Comment: How is `$out` defined?

Comment: `NaN` means not a number. This means that parseFloat doesn't manage to transform skipComma(z) into a float. You should print what happens on z.

Comment: Unex - would you please help with this? How would I go about printing to see what happens on z? (Again - sorry, I'm very new to this.) Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As you should know, your array `$row` is a list of numbers that you add up to make your total in JavaScript.  Adding a line of text will certainly make it notice that it is not a number (`NaN`).

If you want to pass the footer in your JSON array, you'll need to add it somewhere else in the `$out` array.

Comment: Any idea how I would go about doing this? I'm really not certain.

Comment: After `$out[] = $row;`, add `$out[] = "<a href='index.php?p=SOEndingValue&enddate=".$enddate."&startdate=".$startdate."&SalesOrder=".$data['SalesOrder']."' target='_blank'>".
                "$".number_format(($data['EndingValue']),2)."</a>";`.  For the exact code to use in JavaScript, you need to locate how that JSON array is used.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding

```
var n = str.indexOf(">")+1;
var m = str.indexOf("</a>");
z = z.substring(n, m);
```

On `for` loop.

```
for ( var i=0 ; i<aiDisplay.length  ; i++ ) {
  var y = aaData[ aiDisplay[i] ][11];

  var n = str.indexOf(">")+1;
  var m = str.indexOf("</a>");
  var z = y.substring(n, m);

  z = z.replace("$","");
  iTotalPrice5 +=  parseFloat(skipComma(z));
}
```

This will extracts the values between the `<a>` and `</a>` tags, and you can use it for calculations.

Comment: Hm. I tried adding this, but for some reason it prevented any data from being brought into the table. Any idea why that would be? It didn't return $NaN in the footer, it returned $0. But there should definitely be data brought in. Thanks,

Comment: So I figured this out. You were super close. I had to change str to y. so y.indexOf(">")+1; and y.indexOf("</a>");. it works perfectly now. Thanks for the help